# Matching keys to tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have such tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `psAdmin` (
  `id_admin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `enable` CHAR(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `company_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_logged_in_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `valid_account_in_time` CHAR(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expiration_date` DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `psAdminDetails` (
  `id_admin_details` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_admin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nip` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_code` VARCHAR(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `provincial_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar` VARCHAR(65) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` CHAR(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `psAdminLoginAttempts` (
  `id_admin_login_attempts` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_admin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `psAdminLoginHistory` (
  `id_admin_history` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_admin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` VARCHAR(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `psCompany` (
  `id_company` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `enable` CHAR(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` VARCHAR(85) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nip` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `street` VARCHAR(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_code` VARCHAR(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `provincial_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `contact_person` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `www` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` VARCHAR(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_registration` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `psProvincial` (
  `provincial_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `psAdmin`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin`);

ALTER TABLE `psAdminDetails`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin_details`);

ALTER TABLE `psAdminLoginAttempts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin_login_attempts`);

ALTER TABLE `psAdminLoginHistory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin_history`);

ALTER TABLE `psCompany`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_company`);

ALTER TABLE `psProvincial`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`provincial_id`);

ALTER TABLE `psAdmin`
  MODIFY `id_admin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `psAdminDetails`
  MODIFY `id_admin_details` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `psAdminLoginAttempts`
  MODIFY `id_admin_login_attempts` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `psAdminLoginHistory`
  MODIFY `id_admin_history` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `psCompany`
  MODIFY `id_company` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `psProvincial`
  MODIFY `provincial_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

tables have the following functions:

psAdmin - table of administrator logins
psAdminDetails - data table for detailed administrators
psAdminLoginAttempts - table with administrator login attempts
psAdminLoginHistory - table with the administrator's login history
psCompany - company database. Companies can be infinitely many. You can assign administrators to each company
psProvincial - voivodships

It makes sense to combine:

```
psAdminLoginAttempts.id_admin = psAdmin.id_admin
psAdminLoginHistory.id_admin = psAdmin.id_admin
psAdmin.company_id = psCompany.id_company
psAdminDetails.id_admin = psAdmin.id_admin
psAdminDetails.provincial_id = psAdmin.id_admin
psAdminLoginAttempts.id_admin = psAdmin.id_admin
psAdminLoginHistory.id_admin = psAdmin.id_admin
```

Would you add any more keys (eg foreign)? If so, where?

Comment: what's the purpose of the  DB ? do you have main SELECT queries to demonstrate ? I would run EXPLAIN SELECT on all major select commands, and add indexes by that

Comment: At the moment I'm just designing a base. The database is to store administrators assigned to various companies.

Answer (score 0):

I would run EXPLAIN SELECT on all major select commands, and add indexes by that
If there aren't any yet, by default, I would index any field which is a key by definition or any "tag" field, e.g a field I would group by

I would also be careful from indexing VARCHARS, I would use their parallel INT value - company_id instead of company_name. notice not to hold that as a foreign key

my default indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE psAdmin ADD KEY company_id (company_id);
ALTER TABLE psAdmin ADD KEY username (username);

ALTER TABLE psAdminDetails ADD KEY id_admin (id_admin);
ALTER TABLE psAdminDetails ADD KEY country_id (country_id);
ALTER TABLE psAdminDetails ADD KEY provincial_id (provincial_id);

ALTER TABLE psAdminLoginAttempts ADD KEY id_admin (id_admin);

ALTER TABLE psAdminLoginHistory ADD KEY id_admin (id_admin);

ALTER TABLE psAdminLoginHistory ADD KEY country_id (country_id);
```